# In Rails, is it possible to repair model validation errors inside the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

Let's say a model catches a validation error, usually this is handled by the controller, but is it possible to handle it automatically by the model?

Practically I want to generate a unique id `uid` for each `Note`, the model looks like this:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid
  # ... some code to generate uid on after_initialize
end
```

The closest I got is:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid
  # ... some code to generate uid on after_initialize

  after_rollback :repair

  protected

  def repair
    if self.errors[:uid].size > 0
      self.uid = generate_uid
    end
    self.save # Try again
  end
end
```

Some immediate problems with my solution: (1) The model instance still has errors that the controller can see, I'm not sure how to clear the errors. (2) The repair method is recursive.

Comment: I wouldn't go this way. Re-saving a model during before/after filters or validations is an excellent recipe for troubles.

Comment: @ErezRabih is right, besides using a real-uuid generator, i think i would create an additional method like ```save_with_repair``` that just does a retry if the safe fails with a unique constraint.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm sure there is a way to catch and handle the errors in the model (maybe the `after_validation` callback could be of use), perhaps you can avoid the issue in this case by ensuring that the `uid` you generate is unique when you create it.

[Ryan Bates offered this method for generating unique tokens in a RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password):

```
def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

With the use of a `before_create` callback, i.e. `before_create { generate_token(:uid) }`, each model will have a unique id.

All this said, @Beerlington raises a really good point about UUIDs.

**Update:** Note that the method given is expecting to be defined in a `User` model. For your example, you'd want to change it to `...while Note.exists?...`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a true UUID that is guaranteed to be unique, and not add the overhead to your model. Having a uniqueness validation in the model adds some overhead because it has to hit the database to figure out if something exists, and it's still not even guaranteed.

Check out this Ruby project to generate UUIDs: https://github.com/assaf/uuid/